# Related Rates - volume

Tags: calculus

A Spherical balloon is inflated with gas at a rate of 10 cubic feet per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon changing at the instant the radius is 2 feet

is $\frac{dr}{dt} = 10$  ? so im trying to find $\frac{dv}{dt}$ given $r=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find $\frac{dr}{dt}$ ("how fast is the **radius** changing?"). You know the volume is changing: $\frac{dV}{dt} = 10$ (rate is **cubic feet per minute**). You also know $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

Now, use implicit differentiation to relate $\frac{dV}{dt}$ and $\frac{dr}{dt}$. Your formula will include $r$, but this is ok, since you know $r = 2$ at the time you are interested in. (though **do not** make the mistake of plugging in $r = 2$ before you differentiate)

Comment: awesome thank you, i completely misunderstood what the question was asking

Answer (score 1):

You are given:
$$\frac{{\rm d}V}{{\rm d}t}=10$$
And try plugging in $V=\frac43\pi r^3$ and using chain rule to find $\frac{{\rm d}r}{{\rm d}t}$.

**Spoiler: Solution**

> $$10=\frac{\left(\frac43\pi r^3\right)}{{\rm d}t}=4\pi r^2\frac{{\rm d}r}{{\rm d}t}$$

Comment: awesome thank you, i completely misunderstood what the question was asking

Comment: @user231109 ok so are you done?

Comment: yes, solved it now

Answer (score 0):

1.) Take the derivative of the volume formula which will give you the surface area of a sphere.

$V = \frac{4}{3}{\pi}r^{3}$

$\frac{dV}{dr} = 4{\pi}r^{2}{dr}$

2.) Now rearrange and solve for ${dr}$